# container left and right margin on Joomla responsive template

Tags: responsive-design, margin, joomla3.0

I'm working on a responsive template for a Joomla site. (http://www.lyzarr.com/testsite/de/)

Which can a have a left and right sidebar as well as the main container.
Right now the content goes right up to both sides, but I like to have a margin of about 30px both left and right.
Since the template is responsive, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add padding in css file to container-content class,

```
.container-content {
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

and in

```
/templates/your_template/index.php
```

change row class to row-fluid
so your structure will looks like here

```
<div class="container-content">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="content" class="span9"></div>
        <div id="sidebarright" class="span3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in bootstrap 2.3.2 if you use row class, your span* (columns) will have fixed width [span9 = 870px and span3 = 270px]. so if you add left / right padding there will not be enough space for content and column. But if you use row-fluid class, your span* width will be set up in percent value.

Comment: Wow, that's it!
Awesome, I can't thank you enough for this perfekt solution as well as the clear and extremely useful explanation.
Thank you so much!